# Android Studio 3.6.1 | Error: "This project uses AndroidX dependencies"

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I have updated my Android Studio and the `targetSdkVersion` (build.gradle) to 29. I migrated to [AndroidX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_10). Now the Gradle build gives me these two errors:

> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
>
> The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.core:core:1.0.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0

My code is:

#### File *MainActivity.java*

```
package it.manuel.myapp;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIdResult;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *build.gradle*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### File *build.gradle(:app)*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.manuel.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### File *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.manuel.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why doesn't it work any longer?

Comment: Can you check your gradle.properties file that the use AndroidX is set to true or not
 `android.useAndroidX=true`

Answer (score 284, accepted):

> The Android Gradle plugin provides the following global flags that you
> can set in your gradle.properties file:
>
> android.useAndroidX: When set to true, this flag indicates that you
> want to start using AndroidX from now on. If the flag is absent,
> Android Studio behaves as if the flag were set to false.
>
> android.enableJetifier: When set to true, this flag indicates that you
> want to have tool support (from the Android Gradle plugin) to
> automatically convert existing third-party libraries as if they were
> written for AndroidX. If the flag is absent, Android Studio behaves as
> if the flag were set to false.

To enable **jetifier**, add those two lines to your **gradle.properties** file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Ok.. i have insert, now gine me Jackpot allarm :D <br> error: cannot find symbol
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
                                  ^
  symbol: class AppCompatActivity <br> MailActivity give this error..

Comment: @SkleroMc you need to import import `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq This androidx won't react differently than the android, right?

Comment: @MariaIrudayaRegilanJ androidx is different from android support library as it provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases.

Comment: Life would be so much easier if Android Studio would suggest solutions for these kinds of problems with actual usable answers like the two lines you provide! They seem to think a clue that leads to web searches is enough, when they know exactly what would be needed to solve the problem. Thanks for the solution they should have given me.

Comment: Docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

Comment: The gradle.properties is it the global one or the project one?

Comment: Hello, I user cordova for my mobile app development and I am currently facing this issue. whenever I set android.useAndroidX=false and android.enableJetifier=false to android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

then I try running the command again ... the values changes back to default. Please what is the problem

Comment: If you are using Flutter, please check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: I'm having same trouble as @DUG ! the variables get back to the false even after I change them to true.

Comment: I found this file should be modified for `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true` : project_folder\platforms\android\cordova\lib\config\GradlePropertiesParser.js

Comment: @HamidAraghi In my case, it is a cordova related problem. Changing android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true is not sufficient as it requires the project to rebuild every time you want to run the app.
The Ideal solution is to install the cordova-androidx-adapter plugin